# Spring Data JPA Custom Repository with Projection

Tags: java, spring, jpa, projection

I tried to implement a query method with Projections, but I'm not sure if I did it right. I'm new to the world of Spring Boot and don't know exactly how to create a statistics query with Projection. I would be very grateful if you could help me with my problem.

Implement a TestRepository which allows the following query: - A statistics query which

- the number
- per TestKitType
- per TestResult
- for a period of time

```
public class Projections {
    public static record TestKitTypeResultCountRecord(TestKitType testKitType, TestResult testResult, Long count) {}
}


@Repository
public interface TestsRepository extends JpaRepository<Tests,Long> {

    List<Projections.TestKitTypeResultCountRecord> findTestKitTypeResultCountByTestTimeStampBetween(LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate);

}
```